# Evaluating gradiant of vector basis r in Spherical Co-ordinates

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis, fluid-dynamics

If I were to define $\nabla$ in spherical polar co-ordinates:

$$
\nabla=\frac{\partial}{\partial{R}}{\vec{e}_R}+\frac{1}{R}\frac{\partial}{\partial{\theta}}{\vec{e}_{\theta}}+\frac{1}{R\sin{\theta}}\frac{\partial}{\partial{\phi}}{\vec{e}_\phi}
$$

And the basis vector, $\vec{r}$ as:

$$
\vec{r}=R\sin\theta\cos\phi{\vec{e}_R}+R\sin\theta\sin\phi{\vec{e}_\theta}+R\cos\theta{\vec{e}_\phi}
$$

How would I evaluate ${\nabla{\vec{r}}}$? I'm assuming at this point it should equal 1+1+1. I'm just struggling to get there.

For completeness, I am looking to evaluate:

$$
(\vec{A}\cdot{\nabla})\vec{r}=\vec{A}
$$

Comment: $\nabla \vec{r}$ is a two-index object/dyad. Is that really what you want?

Comment: Your expression for $\vec{r}$ is incorrect: $\vec{r}$ is in the direction of $e_R$.

Comment: I'm looking to evaluate the above expression added to the question...

Comment: So would it just be $\vec{r}=R\sin\theta\cos\phi{\vec{e}_{R}}$

Comment: No, $\vec{r}=R e_R$. You're thinking of writing sphericals in Cartesians.